# ID Document , ID Folder SharePoint-Online

Tags: sharepoint, directory, document

My problem is:
if it's possible when we create  document inside the folder (The folder is in the sharepoint library)  take only the ID of the folder...
Exemple:

- I create library "ALPHA",
- I create a folder "Folder One " inside the library , with ID 1.
- Inside the folder "Folder One" I add  05 documents .
  My issue is there documents take different ID of the folder, (document 1 ID=2; document 2 id=2,.....). I want that the ID of these documents take only The ID of the father folder ID=1  (Document 1 ID=1, Document 2 ID =2, ......)

Now I know it's not possible with sharepoint parameter, but I need a custom script to this, but I don't know which language that I use, Where I use it.
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to assign the document with the id of their parent folder. Both Folder and document are items in the SharePoint Library. whether you create a folder or document, it will Occupy an ID placeholder. ID is auto-increasing and not assignable.

Hence I do not think we can operate their ID except we modify the content of SharePoint DB. The possible workaround is that we define a custom column and treat it as ID field.